# Unable to use copy initialization (i.e =) to construct class with initializer list

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std

I would have initially expected the following code to compile:

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  set<int> st;
  A(set<int> s) : st(s) {}
};

int main() {
  A a = {1,2,3}; // Error, couldn't convert from initializer list
  A b({1,2,3}); // Ok
}
```

I can't understand why the first construction fails but the second one succeeds. I tried to replicate the error without the use of initializer list but I couldn't do so.

I am using vc12, but it also fails on the microsoft online visual compiler (with a different error message and code to my compiler).

Should this compile?

If not why not?

EDIT:

The following does compile (EDIT: Only in visual studio and this is a bug.):

```
class A {
public:
  int i;
  A(int j) : i(i) {}
};

class B {
public:
  A a;
  B(A o) : a(o) {}
};

class C {
public:
  B b;
  C(B u) : b(u) {}
};

int main() {
  C c = A(10); // Compiles just fine, but isn't this doing the same set of implicit conversions?
  C v(A(10));
}
```

The two seem the same to me in terms of the number of implicit conversions.

Comment: You're **not** using copy assignment. Rolled back the edit saying "assignment operator" in the title. There is no assignment operator anywhere in the code.

Comment: You've just removed half the question.

Comment: No. There just isn't an assignment operator in sight here, so even though you *thought* the question was about assignment operator, it wasn't. Now the text reflects what the question is really about.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, you removed the entire edit that OP made, **sji** you can edit it back in if you feel it's needed (although as I said in my answer the line you claimed compiles did not compile for me when I tried on ide1).

Comment: @Motti: You need to [check it with a C++11 compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fd0e4aeda649223) or later.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I used C++14 mode of ide1. http://ideone.com/FTR1a3

Comment: Oh. The additional code that I inadvertently deleted. Good that that happened then! :) But I can't make sense of the edit history.

Comment: @Motti It compiles using: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ which I believe is the latest version of visual compiler.

Comment: @sji: This seems like an old bug in Visual C++, observed for at least VS 2013 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700574/multiple-user-defined-conversions-on-initialization), and I confirmed it's there still with VS 2015 update 1.

Comment: I reported the compiler bug, (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2256407/c-two-user-defined-conversions-incorrectly-accepted-in-implicit-conversion-sequence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing an object with `=` the compiler implicitly creates a temporary object of your type and then copies it to your variable (although the temporary and copy may, and usually are, [elided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)).

So your `a` object is theoretically equivalent to:

```
A a = A(std::set<int>({1, 2, 3}));
```

I'm not sure exactly why the behaviour differs but I think it's due to the fact that the compiler is allowed to only perform [one user defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) implicitly. In this case it's probably considered two separate UDCs:

1. initializer list to `std::set`
2. `std::set` to `A`

Comment: See my edit to question, where the 2 implicit conversions would be from A -> B then B -> C if we applied the same rules. I feel like it shouldn't work in that case either due to implicit conversions but it does.

Comment: Except for the wording "assign it to" this answer is correct, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yeah it was clunky, would you say it's better now?

Comment: So the edit shouldn't compile, its just a visual studio bug that it does using http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/? If so then everything makes sense

Answer (score 3):

Given this code:

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  set<int> st;
  A(set<int> s) : st(s) {}
};

int main() {
  A a = {1,2,3}; // Error, couldn't convert from initializer list
  A b({1,2,3}); // Ok
}
```

---

The declaration of `a`, using the “`=`” syntax, is a **copy initialization** with a brace-enclosed list.

If `A` were a Plain Old Data type or an “aggregate” then the values in the list would be used to initialize the items of `a` in order, and the rest of the items, if any, would be zero-initialized.

If `A` instead had a constructor taking a suitable `std::initializer_list` argument, then that would have been used.

Those two possibilities are exhaustive. For example, if the constructor with `std::set` had been considered (it isn't considered), then that would have involved two implicit user-defined conversions to produce the temporary object on the right hand side of `=`, namely `std:initializer_list` → `std::set`, and then `std:.set` → `A`. And the rules of C++ limit an implicit conversion sequence to at most one user defined conversion.

And so, since class `A` is neither POD/aggregate nor a class with `std::initializer_list` construction, you get an error.

---

The declaration of `b` is **direct initialization**. Here the provided argument is used not to produce a temporary `A`, but to produce an argument acceptable to some `A` constructor. One such possibility is found: using the argument to produce a `std::set`.

Answer (score 1):

In first case you are trying to construct your object using constructor which takes an [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as single parameter (which is not implemented). In your second call a temporary `std::set<int>` instance is constructed and your `A(set<int> s)` constructor is called.

In order to fix it implement the missing constructor:

```
A(std::initializer_list<int> list) : st(list) {  }
```

Comment: This isn't true, the first case is trying to initialize from an anonymous `A`.

Comment: @Motti in most modern compilers no temporary/anonymous object constructed and compiler calls an appropriate (if any) constructor directly. In this case it is a constructor with an `initializer_list<int>` as a single parameter.

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that the temporary can be elided but from the language's stand point it's still there (a copy constructor must be valid).

Comment: @Motti not in this case. Adding copy constructor is not required. And adding copy constructor alone doesn't solve the problem. The only thing is required is a constructor with an initializer_list. (tested it in MSVS)

Comment: I'm not saying that you need to add a cctor, I'm saying that if you defined a private cctor then `A a = std::set<int>({1,2})` wouldn't work either. This is proof that the compiler considers `A a = {1,2}` to go via a cctor (even though it's later elided).

Comment: @Motti The constructor is already [implicitly-declared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)